# I am getting "could not find driver " exception while build my laravel application in gitlab CI

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, gitlab-ci

While building my laravel application using gitlab CI/CD ,I am getting the following **exception**:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = xxx and table_name = xxx)

**Here is my .gitlab-yaml file:**

```
image: php:7.2   
services:
  - name: mysql:5.7
variables:
  WITH_XDEBUG: "1"
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_USERNAME: root
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
  MYSQL_DATABASE: xxx
stages:
      - build
      - test
building:
  stage: build
  image: php:7.2
  script:
  - cp .env.test .env
  - php artisan config:clear
  - php artisan migrate:refresh
  - php artisan db:seed
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 month
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
phpunit:
  stage: test
  image: php:7.2
  script:
    - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --verbose --configuration phpunit.xml
```

**Please find my .env.test below:**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=somestring

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxx

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=xxx
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mysql` driver is missing from your server, I got the same error, I resolved it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mysql
```

You can replace the php version, according to your server php version, Also once done with the above command you can run the following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

The above command clear your server cache and restart your server.